# Number format PHP european format (= 3.213.124,4355) without 0's in decimal

Tags: php

I want to convert numbers as follow in PHP:

```
100000 -> 100.000
3213 -> 3.213
54523.321 -> 54.523,321
42324.00 -> 42.324
3412.1 -> 3.412,1
```

So I want to have the . as thousands seperator and the , as decimal seperator and I don't want the use-less 0 in the decimal. How can I do this?

I know that I can use float to get rid of the 0's after decimal. And I know that I can use number_format to replace the thousands/decimal seperator, but in that case you also have to define the number of decimals and you will get 0's in the decimal...

Comment: "I know that I can use float to get rid of the 0's after decimal" - no, you cast to an integer or use the round() function.

Comment: _“but in that case you also have to define the number of decimals and you will get 0's in the decimal”_ - well then replace a trailing `,00` in the result with an empty string …?

Comment: "european format" - which european format? There are several. Both the server and the client have some details on how to present numbers (and dates, and other things) for different localities - but the means by which this data is accessed differs depending on the server operating system and other considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer by myself (with using/changing code that I found in comments on [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) ):

```
function number_format_unchanged_precision($number, $dec_point='.', $thousands_sep=','){
    if($dec_point==$thousands_sep){
        trigger_error('2 parameters for ' . __METHOD__ . '() have the same value, that is "' . $dec_point . '" for $dec_point and $thousands_sep', E_USER_WARNING);
        // It corresponds "PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for number_format()", which occurs when you use $dec_point without $thousands_sep to number_format().
    }
    $decimals = strlen(substr(strrchr($number, "."), 1));

    return number_format($number, $decimals, $dec_point, $thousands_sep);
}
```

and here also a function that includes rounding, but doesn't add the useless 0's: (I think the normal number_format() function should work like this...)

```
function number_format_without_zeroindecimal($number, $maxdecimal, $dec_point='.', $thousands_sep=','){
    if($dec_point==$thousands_sep){
        trigger_error('2 parameters for ' . __METHOD__ . '() have the same value, that is "' . $dec_point . '" for $dec_point and $thousands_sep', E_USER_WARNING);
        // It corresponds "PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for number_format()", which occurs when you use $dec_point without $thousands_sep to number_format().
    }
    $decimals = strlen(substr(strrchr(round($number,$maxdecimal), "."), 1));

    return number_format($number, $decimals, $dec_point, $thousands_sep);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [`number_format()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) as following:

```
$number = 1234.5600;
$nb = number_format($number, 2, ',', '.'); // 1.234,56
```

It'll remove all of the zeroes at the end of the decimals automatically.

Comment: I'm a sticker to providing links to documentation, therefore I edited your answer.

Comment: but if $number is 1234.00 this wil give 1.234,00 instead of 1.234 ..... That's my problem/question! :)

Comment: @Robbert just use then `floatval(number_format($number, 2, ',', '.'))` and voilà :-)

Comment: thanks, but that will also give 1.234 for your $1234.5600 ... So i'm looking for the function that will just remove all 0's in decimal and use right seperators. Or is this not possible with standard PHP functions? Furthermore floatval gives also strange result for $number = 12345600; (12.345 instead of 12.345.600)